# How do I make an attribute Boolean as [Required] to use with a RadioButtonFor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to create an attribute and add the DataAnnotation `[Required]` to use with `RadioButtonFor`. This `RadioButtonFor` when the page is loaded it is `unchecked` and I need this because the user need to choose one of two options (yes/no) to next step. The problem is I can't make this attribute required.

How could I do this ?

**Model**

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please, choose one option")]
public Boolean isGroupMember { get; set; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="@Html.IdFor(model => model.isGroupMember )" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Choose one option ? <img src="~/Imagens/required.png" height="6" width="6" title="requerido"></label>
                        <table class="table">
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>Yes</strong>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.isGroupMember , 1, new { Class = "form-control" })</td>
                                <td><strong>No</strong>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.isGroupMember , 0, new { Class = "form-control" })</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table> 
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.isGroupMember )                     
                    </div><!--/member group-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 2 possible values of a boolean field is `true` and `false`. The default value of the boolean field is `false`. So even if the user did not select anything in the form, When the model validation framework inspects the value of this property, the value(`false`,*default value*)  is a valid boolean value, hence will pass the model validation.

To make the required validation works, you need to make it a [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) boolean type

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please, choose one option")]
public Boolean? isGroupMember2 { get; set; }
```

I would also suggest switching to PascalCasing for property names (`IsGroupMember2` instead of `isGroupMember2`)

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please, choose one option")]
public bool? IsGroupMember2 { get; set; }
```

You also probable want to change the value of the radio buttons to `True` and `False` instead of `1` and `0`.

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsGroupMember , true, new { Class = "form-control" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsGroupMember , false, new { Class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing your radio buttons with the following code.

```
<td><strong>Yes</strong>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.isGroupMember , 1, new { Class = "form-control" }, required = "required")</td>
<td><strong>No</strong>@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.isGroupMember , 0, new { Class = "form-control" },required = "required")</td>
```